# Sci-Fi Novel - Humans are slaves to aliens who enjoy intoxication, circa 1985-ish

Tags: story-identification, novel

A book I never finished that I think of several times a year. I recall very little of this book, only that it has tormented me for nearly 30 years. What I do remember is that humans are slaves to an alien race, and at the end of their day, the aliens enjoy inhaling an intoxicating substance. I also seem to recall that either the aliens or the humans have to wear some kind of air breather. And that unfortunately is about it. I know it's not much to go on, but I do not think stoned aliens are a common theme, so I am hopeful it will ring some bells.

It was a novel, in English, in America. It was most definitely not from a magazine or a collection of short stories. I can still recall taking the book off of the shelf several times from our small library of books, in sixth grade English class.

Comment: The standard questions: what language was it in, and what country did you get it in?  You refer to it as a "book"; does that mean you remember it as being an entire book, as opposed to a short story in a collection or a magazine?  If it was a book, do you recall anything of the cover?  Any character names?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 20):

My first thought would be [The Tripods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods), a series of 3 books from John Christopher (released 1967-68). I had a all 3 in 1 book version of this, so maybe you had the same version. there was also a later 4th book as prequel, but i did not read that.

Humans are enslaved by aliens called "Tripods"

> Life goes on largely as it had in the pre-industrial era, excepting
>   that all adult humans are subject to Tripod control. Protagonist Will,
>   a thirteen-year-old boy living in the (fictional) English village of
>   Wherton, is looking forward to the next "Capping Day", until a chance
>   meeting with a mysterious uncapped man named Ozymandias prompts him to
>   discover a world beyond the Tripods' control.

They are using breath masks:

> Slaves are furnished with breathing masks to survive the aliens'
>   atmosphere, but are rapidly exhausted by the stronger artificial
>   gravity and must therefore be periodically replaced. Although Fritz is
>   abused by his Master, Will is treated as a pet by his. Eventually,
>   Will's Master reveals a plan to replace the Earth's atmosphere with
>   the Masters' toxic air to enable full control of the Earth.

Also some of the aliens use something drug-like:

> At least some Masters enjoy an intoxicant they call (for the purposes
>   of their slaves) a gas bubble. The master places the plastic bubble
>   near his respiratory orifice and breaks it, then inhaling the vapor.
>   The effect is evidently mild; it takes several such bubbles to create
>   personality changes noticeable to humans. Use of gas bubbles brought
>   out latent personality traits in at least one Master.

There was also a famous [tv-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_%28TV_series%29) about this.

Comment: @JohnShepherd - Tripods was pretty commonly stocked in most libraries I knew in the NE of USA, and the breathers and the intoxicants were featured more in the second book, *The City of Gold and Lead*, which had a closer look at the aliens in question, and might have been the specific book you read.

Comment: The Tripods for the win!! Thanks so much, that is definitely the story!!!

Answer (score 5):

This reminds me of Battlefield Earth by L Ron Hubbard. In this book the earth has been turned into a mining colony by a race of large aliens called Psychlos. They need air masks to survive earth's atmosphere. Humans also need air masks to survive in the psychlo compounds. I remember references to the Psychlos being intoxicated fairly often, but I cannot remember if the intoxicant is airbourne.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to take a look at the book. I initially dismissed that it could be Battlefield Earth, because the movie does not evoke any recollections, but that doesn't mean much.

Comment: Of all the books that became films.....Battlefield Earth the movie is one of those where the title of the movie and maybe a character name here and there seems to be the only relationship between the two...

Comment: The Psychlos intoxicant is called kerbango, and is drunk, not inhaled, IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

### Julain May's The Saga of Pliocene Exile?

Published in the early 1980's, consisted of four books:

- *The Many Colored Land*
- *The Golden Torc*
- *The Nonborn King*
- *The Adversary*

Specifically in the first two books, humans time-travel back to the Pliocene era of earth history, only to discover there are aliens there.

**Slavery**

The aliens are enslaving the humans. The summary [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) (bold added) will do:

> The Tanu exotics have difficulty reproducing on Earth due to the high terrestrial and solar radiation, relative to their homeworld, and so
>   have **enslaved many of the humans in an effort to overcome this
>   problem, interbreeding with the more robust humans**. The Firvulag
>   exotics are, in the main, unaffected by the higher levels of radiation
>   and have no reproductive challenges

and

> Though ramapithecine apes are made to do a lot of the menial labor in
>   the Tanu kingdom, **human grey torc slaves end up doing the more complex
>   and dangerous grunt work**.
>
> In order to increase their population more rapidly, the Tanu have been using humans as breeding stock ever since they arrived. The human women have their tubal ligation reversed. Those human women who are metapsychically gifted or have some unique, highly desired talent are often **married off** to Tanu nobles, after they each have spent one night with King Thagdal. Thagdal is very fertile (which is the main reason he is king) so many of **the women who are forced to sleep with him** are impregnated. **Those human women who are less talented but are beautiful end up in houses of pleasure where they are forced to service the sexual needs of Tanu.** Any children resulting from this sexual slavery are separated from their mothers at birth and are placed in adoption with a Tanu couple, to be raised as Tanu.
>
> Human males are also **forced to become genetic donors**. Those humans who are metapsychically or aesthetically gifted are used by Tanu women who desire to have children. **The human males are not allowed to refuse the sexual attentions of the Tanu.** Many human men however find this duty not onerous at all as the Tanu ladies are often quite beautiful, exotic, and metapsychically gifted thus able to enhance the man's pleasure far beyond what sex with human women can provide. Others less able to tolerate this quickly become burnt out due to repeated metapsychic trauma

**Drinking**

The slavery began through some seduction that involved drinking, and the Tanu could hold their drink well (if I recall). An excerpt here from *[The Golden Torc](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZYgv758W_YoC&lpg=PT173&ots=HaEblicj86&dq=golden%20torc%20julian%20may%20drunk&pg=PT57#v=onepage&q=drunk%20OR%20drink%20OR%20wine%20OR%20slave&f=false)* (29-30):

> "To the Tanu race and the human race! In fellowship, in communion, in love!"
>
> The **feasters raised their great golden goblets**. "Fellowship! Communion! Love!"
>
> "With an emphasis on the latter!" called out Aiken Drum.
>
> There was laughter and shouting and **a great swallowing and spilling of wine, with many a soggy embrace and a sipping from lip to lip**. The royal couple, **inflamed by the drink** and festivity, now clung to each other murmuring and snorting. A corps de ballet of human women and men, dressed alike in bold magpie leotards, appeared as music struck up and began to lead the throng in elaborate contredanse patterns.
>
> ...
>
> One of the female black-and-whiters tried to haul Bryan off his bench into the dance, where Aiken and Raimo were already whirling and leaping as though they had been doing the complex steps all their lives. Bryan shook his head to the invitation. **He let the waiters fill his great cup again and again** and tried to blot from his mind the realization of how it must be now with Mercy.
>
> When he finally thought to examine the cup closely and discovered what the gold and jewels ensheathed, he was too **drunk** to care.

There are other passages that indicate the use of alcohol by the aliens and the humans, such that it was significant enough in the early books to have been remembered as a major part of the story.

**Air breathing device?**

There is not any major need for this that I can recall in the books, for either human or alien. However, given your age at the time, perhaps you are misremembering the purpose of the torcs themselves, worn around the necks of both humans and aliens for various purposes related to psychic powers and control. Again from the Wikipedia article (bold added):

> There are **three kinds of torc** made by the Tanu: **gold, silver and grey.**
>   Gold Torcs are the original version, worn by all pure-blooded Tanu, as
>   well as the inhabitants of the Daughter Worlds back in the Duat
>   Galaxy. **A gold torc makes a person with latent powers completely
>   operant in those powers.**
>
> Dr. Eusebio Gomez-Nolan, a human who was given the name Sebi-Gomnol by
>   the Tanu, invented the silver and grey torcs, along with much
>   simplified torc-like devices for controlling the ramapithecine apes
>   which do the drudge work in Tanu society. These lesser torcs allow for
>   control of the wearer by any gold torc wearer.
>
> **Silver Torcs give operancy equal to that of the gold, but unlike the
>   gold torc they also incorporate control circuitry.** This allows a gold
>   torc wearer to compel obedience in the silver torc wearer, allows for
>   punishment or reward of the silver torc wearer via so-called
>   pleasure-pain circuitry, and act as a means of mentally tracking the
>   wearer. (Therefore, a silver torc wearer can never succeed in running
>   away, unless their metaphysical talent is so great it burns out the
>   torc circuitry (see Aiken)). Humans with significant latent powers who
>   come through the time-gate are initially given silver torcs. This
>   allows the Tanu a degree of control over them until they prove
>   themselves trustworthy, at which point they may be given a gold torc.
>
> **Grey Torcs do not enhance metapsychic powers at all, although they do
>   grant the wearer a much simplified version of Farspeech. They have
>   control circuitry like that found in the silver torcs.** They are given
>   to humans with no significant latent metapsychic powers at all, but
>   who have skills which the Tanu consider to be vital or sensitive, e.g.
>   physicians, technicians, soldiers/guards

Comment: While I likes me some Julian May (read the Galactic Milieu but not the Pliocene) and am tempted to upvote , there are so many other distinctive elements (as you show) that I would think something else would have come out of OPs memory.

Comment: @Radhil: If you like May, you should read The Saga of Pliocene Exile, as it is the background for the Galactic Milieu (and vice versa, which is what happens when time travel is dealt with in sci-fi). The reason I offered the answer was his final statement: "I can still recall taking the book off of the shelf several times from our small library of books, in sixth grade English class." That sounds like he may not have read  it entirely, just in pieces, and being roughly age 12, _might_ have mis-understood/remembered why the torc (necklaces) were being worn. I am interested in OP feedback.